# Failure when casting NULL/nullptr to std::function<>&

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010, visual-c++-2013

This code fails to build in VC2013:    (EDIT: I'm not asking why it fails to build)

```
#include <functional>

struct MyStruct
{
    std::function<void()> m_Func;
    MyStruct( const std::function<void()>& func) :  m_Func(func)   {}
};


int main()
{
    MyStruct rc( NULL );
    return 0;
}
```

With error:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(283): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(228) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<int,false>::_ApplyX<_Rx,>(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Rx=void
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(228) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<int,false>::_ApplyX<_Rx,>(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Rx=void
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(226) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::_Func_impl<_MyWrapper,_Alloc,_Ret,>::_Do_call(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>  ,            _Ret=void
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(495) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Func_impl<_MyWrapper,_Alloc,_Ret,>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>  ,            _Ret=void
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(396) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Ty,_Alloc>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>  ,            _Fty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(396) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Ty,_Alloc>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>  ,            _Fty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(385) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,>>>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Fty=int
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(385) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<std::_Func_class<_Ret,>>>(_Fty &&,_Alloc)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Fty=int
1>  ,            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<void,>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(671) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset<_Ty>(_Fty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Fty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\functional(671) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Reset<_Ty>(_Fty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>  ,            _Fty=int
1>          ]
1>          f:\work\teststdfunction\teststdfunction.cpp(16) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (void)>::function<int>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fx=int
1>          ]
1>          f:\work\teststdfunction\teststdfunction.cpp(16) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (void)>::function<int>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fx=int
1>          ]
```

(Note the '_Fx=int' at the last two reported errors).

I can live with that, as changing `MyStruct rc(NULL)` to `MyStruct rc(nullptr)` solves the error.   Two things however remain a mystery:

1) Removing the const qualifier from MyStruct ctor (`MyStruct( std::function<void()>& func)` gives a very, very different error:

> 1>f:\work\main\dev\common\teststdfunction\teststdfunction\teststdfunction.cpp(16):
>   error C2664: 'MyStruct::MyStruct(const MyStruct &)' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'int' to 'std::function &'

Which makes more sense than the original error, and now fixing NULL to nullptr *doesn't* solve it.  Why does int (or nullptr) refuse to cast to `std::function<>&` but agree to cast to a `const std::function<>&` ?

2) The original code compiles and works as expected in VS2010.   Is it an obscure VS2010 library bug?

---

EDIT:
As far as the const/non const question goes, I now think the casting involved and potential type mismatch are probably a red herring.  The argument passed - either NULL or nullptr - is a literal and thus a const. It just cannot bind to a non const reference.   For example:

```
const int& a = 8;   // Ok
int& b = 9;    // error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int &'
```

Does that sound right?  Am I still missing something?

Comment: `nullptr` is a value of type `nullptr_t` which is what the constructor of `std::function` accepts. `NULL` is not necessarily defined as `nullptr` and may be a different value. Use `nullptr` not `NULL.

Comment: As noted, I did change to nullptr.  I'm not asking why the original code didn't compile.

Comment: Literals are NOT CONST AT ALL. They are rvalues. This is a totally different thing. Do not propagate that incorrect myth.

Comment: Why did you revert my edit? The modified code works in VS as well and is actually standard conforming.

Comment: @pmr - are you asking me?   I didn't revert any edit, but I did add my own edit that might have accidentally overrun yours (if we did it simultaneously). My apologies.

Comment: @OfekShilon Yes, this was directed towards you. Have a look at the history of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27343594/revisions

Comment: @pmr, I restored your edit. Seems we did edit it in parallel.

Comment: @Puppy: AFAIK literals are both rvalues *and* constants.  MSDN mentions it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c70dax92.aspx)  and even refers explicitly to an exception regarding string literals, dropped in C++11 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx, 'microsoft specific').  Did I/MS got it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special here has to do with constructor template constraints and other implicit conversions.

The reason why `nullptr` works is because `std::function` has a particular constructor taking it. This constructor will always be the best match for that argument because function templates are ranked as lower preference, all else being equal.

Normally, `0` will implicitly convert to `nullptr` and that's fine. The problem is that it can *also* be passed to the unconstrained function template constructor which constructs from function objects. This does not require an implicit conversion, so all is not equal, so this constructor is preferred- which results in the error that you see that `int` is not a valid function object.

libstdc++ and libc++ don't not exhibit this behaviour because they have implemented the C++14 fix for this problem, which constrains the constructor. C++11 did not so this behaviour is quite conforming for a C++11 implementation.

This kind of issue is why `NULL` is a terrible thing that you shouldn't use. In fact, the VS2010 team had to rush `nullptr` out the door as an additional feature in the last minute because `NULL` interacts so badly with every other feature in C++, ever, and especially with C++11.

For `const` vs non-`const` references, other answers have explained that issue adequately.

There are other WTFs you can find when using `std::function` without the constrained constructor fix shipped in C++14- this isn't the only one. The long and short is that it's a defect in the C++11 Standard, and *not* in VS. VS2010 compiling it is probably a compiler overload resolution bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I still don't understand is why SFINAE doesn't kick in. Say 0 did match the unconstrained template but failed spectacularly afterwards - shouldn't the nullptr_t specialization be tried next for a match?

Comment: @Ofek: SFINAE only applies to the function signature. It does not apply to the body generally.

Answer (score 0):

Casting a `T` to a `U&` never works, and that's intentionally. You can cast to a `U const&`. The reason is that changes to the temporary U object wouldn't propagate back to the T value.

VS2010 is slightly buggy in this respect, and did allow the cast (but with the proper settings, will warn about it)

Comment: Not sure I understand. Obviously void f(int& i) can accept an int - doesn't that qualify as casting from T to U&?

Comment: @OfekShilon: No, it can't: `f(4)` is rejected despite `4` being an obvious `int`. And that's just `T` to `T&` - you can't change `4` either.

Comment: isn't 4 a *const* int?    AFAIK The failure to bind 4 to an int& is double:   (a) it is const, (b) it is an rvalue.

Comment: 4 is const int that's why it cannot be int&. As it is mentioned it is MSVC extension. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/     (See: Binding a non-const reference to a temporary)

Comment: @NN_: Reasonable as it may sound, no, `4` is not a `const int`. It's an _prvalue_, in Standardese. And non-class non-array prvalues cannot be cv-qualified. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category